# How to Use Facebook as my Sites Login?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have some doubt, about FB Log in system integration in my website , how can i use it??
Like am i need to save anything in my db, more over how can i get a sample code in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to implement what is known as [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/108). Have a look at this tutorial on how to integrate facebook connect in your site:

- [Facebook Connect Tutorial](http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/tutorial.php) (DEPRECATED)

Or

- [Facebook Connect Video Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/177)

You can make the integration with few clicks using [Facebook Connect Wizard](http://developers.facebook.com/setup/) in three steps :)

Comment: Facebook connect is deprecated DONT use it

Comment: Use the Facebook for websites link below and follow their single sign-on example

Comment: @BeRecursive: Got what exactly you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with [Facebook for Websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web)